# Communication between chain vuejs components

Tags: vue.js

I want to communicate between two separated components. they are not parent and child component.

I knew there two ways to communicate between parent and child component. but, communication between separated components I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement EventBus to communicate between different components. Create another vue instance just for Events.

vueEventManager.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

class vueEventManager {
  constructor() {
      this.vue = new Vue;
  }
  trigger(event, data = null) {
      this.vue.$emit(event, data);
  }
  listen(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$on(event, callback);
  }
  off(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$off(event, callback);
  }
  once(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$once(event, callback);
  }
}

export default vueEventManager;
```

Then you can register it in your main.js file:

```
import vueEventManager from './folder/vueeventmanager';
window.EventsBus = new vueEventManager();
```

Now you can use it in your components to emit events.

```
EventsBus.trigger('eventName', {'valueName': value})
```

And listen to them

```
created() { //registering listener it in created hook
    EventsBus.listen('eventName', (value) => {
            //do something
          });
}
```

Comment: The event bus is a great way to handle smpile components communication. For big complex applications, you may use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as a data store to share data between different components.

Comment: `window.Event = new vueEventManager();` this will cause a big issue; overwriting the main javaScript `Event` object. If you want to bind the event bus to the window, you have chosen another name. For example  `window.EventsBus = new vueEventManager();`